# How many ways can we solve a system of n linear equations using only substitution method?

Tags: combinatorics, linear-transformations

Suppose we have n linear equations which are all independent of each other, then how many possible ways could we solve them?

By that I mean, how many different computer algorithms can we write which solves them by restricting ourself to the substitution method solving linear equations.

For example, if we have two linear equations: $$a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$$ and $$a_2x +b_2 y+c_2=0$$

Then we have eight ways of solving. Explanation, first we have two option for first equation we start with, then we have two option for variable to isolate, after that, we substitute the isolate variable in the other equation to find the isolate variable and reverse substitute for the remaining one.

Comment: How would you define equivalence on the set of computer algorithms? For example, I can make a program that will begin by using the equation with the biggest coefficient on $x$ to substitute $x$ out of all other equations or I could make a program that does the same thing except when that coefficient is equal to 14. In this way I can make infinitely many different computer programs.

Comment: I am speaking for a given set of equations. It could be in that, certain equations those two algorithims agree @Poseidaan, hence would be counted once, others twice, since they don't. Think of it like, what gets choosen rather than the choosing rule in itself

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing the argument in the question:

With $n$ unknowns and $n$ equations there are $n^2$ ways to choose an equation and then a variable to isolate and substitute in the other equations. That means there are
$$
n^2(n-1)^2\cdots 1^2 = n!^2
$$
ways to work your way down. Substituting back calls for no choices. You just work out the values of the variables in the order in which you isolated them.

This count fails in some particular cases. If you start with the equations
$$
x + 1 = 0, \quad y + 3 = 0
$$
you can decide which to solve first, but don't have a choice then about which variable to isolate.

You must also take into account the possibility that your system has no solutions, or multiple solutions.

In practice, substitution is a poor method for solving systems of equations. There are much more efficient robust algorithms.

Comment: This is not right, in the 2x2 case, the equation gets auto solved by my procedure. In 3x3 case, you'd have to do more reverse substitution steps, and it is arbitary which variables you solve first when you reverse substitute so

Comment: In the $3 \times 3$ case when you have solved for one variable (say it was $x$) then in the previous step you had two equations in two unknowns - they would be $x$ and $y$ if you chose to isolate $z$ in the first step. So you use the value of $x$ to solve for $y$, then both to solve for $z$. No choices on the way back up.

Comment: Okay, good point, but you've actually answered only a simpler version of my question. You assume that we substitute into the other two at once, I think of it rather as we have to do subtitutions in a step. So we'd have two possibilities depending which of the remaining two we substitute the third equation into first

Comment: If you were to write a literal computer algorithim, then it would be clear cut that these two would be two different algorithims

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller You should be able to calculate the factor that increases the count for the version you suggest. I think it's another $n!$.